# Sort rows within data blocks in a file. Move rows in one block to a different location in the data block based on index in a column

Tags: bash, file, sorting, awk, text-processing

I have data in a file that is arranged as below. This shows only two data blocks/iterations.

```
     21 ! <-- This is the number of lines of data in the data block/iteration.  It never changes.
 Linkages. Iteration:1_1010 ! <-- This number does not always increase by 5 like in this example, but always increases.
  A         1.010      -3.582      -3.135
  B         0.730      -4.428      -3.854
  B        -3.883       4.671       0.010
  A        -0.223       2.522      -4.893
  B         2.769       4.634       0.179
  B        -2.024      -3.640      -1.032
  A         4.613       3.914       1.567
  B         2.746      -0.545       1.430
  B        -0.532       3.380      -2.107
  C         3.944       2.513      -5.172
  C        -4.669       1.056       2.747
  C         0.645       0.001      -3.737
  C        -2.875      -1.233      -0.538
  C         4.279      -5.187      -2.820
  C         1.067      -2.279       2.021
  C         2.667      -1.558       0.588
  C         3.628      -0.025       2.464
  C        -0.023       1.717       1.175
  C         0.925      -1.548       2.273
  C         1.152       2.914       1.039
  C         0.878      -0.445      -0.948
     21
 Linkages. Iteration:1_1015 
  A         1.010      -3.582      -3.135
  B         0.730      -4.428      -3.854
  B        -3.883       4.671       0.010
  A        -0.223       2.522      -4.893
  B         2.769       4.634       0.179
  B        -2.024      -3.640      -1.032
  A         4.613       3.914       1.567
  B         2.746      -0.545       1.430
  B        -0.532       3.380      -2.107
  C         3.944       2.513      -5.172
  C        -4.669       1.056       2.747
  C         0.645       0.001      -3.737
  C        -2.875      -1.233      -0.538
  C         4.279      -5.187      -2.820
  C         1.067      -2.279       2.021
  C         2.667      -1.558       0.588
  C         3.628      -0.025       2.464
  C        -0.023       1.717       1.175
  C         0.925      -1.548       2.273
  C         1.152       2.914       1.039
  C         0.878      -0.445      -0.948
```

What I need to do is redistribute the "C" lines.  Specifically, I need to divide the "C" lines into blocks of four, then move the first block of C lines below the first set of "ABB" lines.  Here is an example for one data block/iteration (I would like to do the exact same thing for all data blocks/iterations in the file):

```
    21 
Linkages. Iteration:1_1010
  A         1.010      -3.582      -3.135
  B         0.730      -4.428      -3.854
  B        -3.883       4.671       0.010
  C         3.944       2.513      -5.172
  C        -4.669       1.056       2.747
  C         0.645       0.001      -3.737
  C        -2.875      -1.233      -0.538
  A        -0.223       2.522      -4.893
  B         2.769       4.634       0.179
  B        -2.024      -3.640      -1.032
  C         4.279      -5.187      -2.820
  C         1.067      -2.279       2.021
  C         2.667      -1.558       0.588
  C         3.628      -0.025       2.464
  A         4.613       3.914       1.567
  B         2.746      -0.545       1.430
  B        -0.532       3.380      -2.107
  C        -0.023       1.717       1.175
  C         0.925      -1.548       2.273
  C         1.152       2.914       1.039
  C         0.878      -0.445      -0.948
```

I have been trying to do this in bash using "sort" but have not made much progress.  I have found out that the general way to sort by a column index (like my first column) is to do this:

```
sort -n -k1 file
```

I also found this post (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99582/sorting-blocks-of-lines) where the second answer uses "split" to split a file into blocks made of four lines:

```
split -a 6 -l 4 input_file my_prefix_
```

But I can't figure out how to move the four lines witih a data block/iteration.  If anyone knows of a resource that explains this, it would be great to find out.

Comment: The last example is what you should get? If so, if you sort by column 1, there should be A, then B, then C. Why not? And perhaps you should look in a more versatile language for that (java, python, perl, ...).

Comment: @NoDataFound, I edited the question.  Yes, the last example is what I'm aiming for.  I want four "C" lines for each set of "ABB."  The first set of ABB with the top four CCCC lines, then the second set of ABB with the second set of CCCC lines, and so on.

Comment: This looks like a complicated `awk` or `python` script. `awk` might be just enough and ok to use. Learn awk from various online tutorials. Then read whole one chunk all lines into one array. Then after reading it output the array elements in the specific order you want - first `1,2,3` elements, then `10,11,12,13` elements, and so on.

Comment: @KamilCuk, thank you for that advice.  Are you saying that bash is not going to work for this?  I know a little Awk but not enough to tackle this, sadly.

Comment: `Are you saying that bash is not going to work for this?` No. Bash (pure bash) is going to work, it's going to be super slow in bash. Bash is a shell, shell is for running other programs. Awk is for parsing files. But surely looks do-able in some bash loops.

Comment: @KamilCuk, it is OK if it is slow.  I have tried searching out Awk solutions but can't get anywhere because my Awk skills aren't good enough.

Comment: the expected output is missing all of the lines for the `Iteration:1_1015` block; was this intentional and if so what's the logic for determining when to skip/drop a block of lines? or was this (leaving out this block of lines) an oversight?

Comment: @markp-fuso, yes, I did do this intentionally because I didn't want to overwhelm people.  The 1_1015 block and all other blocks in the file should be formatted the same way.  I mentioned I did it only for one data block/iteration but if it is confusing, I can edit it.  Thank you for asking.

Comment: @Ant my apologies ... re-reading the entire question and I see you did state this; I've got a habit of scanning the input/expected-output blocks to get the big picture ... and when I see a disconnect (input data missing from expected-output) ... ; in my defense, I haven't had my first cup of caffeine for the day ...

Comment: @markp-fuso, no problem at all!  My writing can be too flowery and I like getting feedback on how to be clearer.  Just mentioned it in case it would help the question make more sense.

Comment: @Ant regarding your comments about trying to do this in bash because you don't know awk well enough. I don't mean this in a mean way but obviously you don't know bash well enough either since you asked the question, and awk is the right tool for the job while bash is the wrong one so you should focus on learning how to do this in awk rather than learning how to do it in bash.

Comment: @EdMorton, I agree.  I have slowly been learning Awk but can still only handle simple tasks.  I wouldn't be able to write what I need in this situation from scratch.  It will be very helpful to have the examples the other commenters have kindly provided because I'll be able to learn a lot from adapting them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 ~ /^[ABC]$/ {
    vals[++numVals] = $0
    next
}
{
    prtVals()
    print
}
END { prtVals() }

function prtVals(       row,valNr,blocks,numBlocks,blockNr,numCs) {
    if ( numVals != 0 ) {
        for (valNr=1; valNr<=numVals; valNr++) {
            row = vals[valNr]
            split(row,f)
            if ( f[1] == "A" ) {
                ++numBlocks
            }
            if ( f[1] == "C" ) {
                if ( (++numCs % 4) == 1 ) {
                    blockNr++
                }
                blocks[blockNr] = blocks[blockNr] row ORS
            }
            else {
                blocks[numBlocks] = blocks[numBlocks] row ORS
            }
        }
        for (blockNr=1; blockNr<=numBlocks; blockNr++) {
            printf "%s", blocks[blockNr]
        }
        delete vals
        numVals = 0
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
     21 ! <-- This is the number of lines of data in the data block/iteration.  It never changes.
 Linkages. Iteration:1_1010 ! <-- This number does not always increase by 5 like in this example, but always increases.
  A         1.010      -3.582      -3.135
  B         0.730      -4.428      -3.854
  B        -3.883       4.671       0.010
  C         3.944       2.513      -5.172
  C        -4.669       1.056       2.747
  C         0.645       0.001      -3.737
  C        -2.875      -1.233      -0.538
  A        -0.223       2.522      -4.893
  B         2.769       4.634       0.179
  B        -2.024      -3.640      -1.032
  C         4.279      -5.187      -2.820
  C         1.067      -2.279       2.021
  C         2.667      -1.558       0.588
  C         3.628      -0.025       2.464
  A         4.613       3.914       1.567
  B         2.746      -0.545       1.430
  B        -0.532       3.380      -2.107
  C        -0.023       1.717       1.175
  C         0.925      -1.548       2.273
  C         1.152       2.914       1.039
  C         0.878      -0.445      -0.948
     21
 Linkages. Iteration:1_1015
  A         1.010      -3.582      -3.135
  B         0.730      -4.428      -3.854
  B        -3.883       4.671       0.010
  C         3.944       2.513      -5.172
  C        -4.669       1.056       2.747
  C         0.645       0.001      -3.737
  C        -2.875      -1.233      -0.538
  A         1.010      -3.582      -3.135
  B         0.730      -4.428      -3.854
  B        -3.883       4.671       0.010
  C         3.944       2.513      -5.172
  C        -4.669       1.056       2.747
  C         0.645       0.001      -3.737
  C        -2.875      -1.233      -0.538
  A        -0.223       2.522      -4.893
  B         2.769       4.634       0.179
  B        -2.024      -3.640      -1.032
  C         4.279      -5.187      -2.820
  C         1.067      -2.279       2.021
  C         2.667      -1.558       0.588
  C         3.628      -0.025       2.464
  A        -0.223       2.522      -4.893
  B         2.769       4.634       0.179
  B        -2.024      -3.640      -1.032
  C         4.279      -5.187      -2.820
  C         1.067      -2.279       2.021
  C         2.667      -1.558       0.588
  C         3.628      -0.025       2.464
  A         4.613       3.914       1.567
  B         2.746      -0.545       1.430
  B        -0.532       3.380      -2.107
  C        -0.023       1.717       1.175
  C         0.925      -1.548       2.273
  C         1.152       2.914       1.039
  C         0.878      -0.445      -0.948
  A         4.613       3.914       1.567
  B         2.746      -0.545       1.430
  B        -0.532       3.380      -2.107
  C        -0.023       1.717       1.175
  C         0.925      -1.548       2.273
  C         1.152       2.914       1.039
  C         0.878      -0.445      -0.948
```

Comment: thank you!  When I understand what's going on here, I'll know I have made some progress with Awk!  I am looking forward to figuring this out.

Comment: The bulk of the code (the prtVals() function would look essentially the same written in C, Python, Pascal, or any other Algol-based language) and the few remaining lines above it are hopefully very clear and obvious in what they do so I expect it won't take you much effort to figure the whole thing out and then please feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: that is very generous.  Thank you so much.  Yes, you're right.  I am feeling like I'm on more familiar ground now you've pointed that out.

Comment: I had a hard time figuring out the basics but once it worked, it was noticeably very fast.  I will be thinking about why that is because it is an advantage for what I'm doing.  I only wish I could give the other commenters credit too.  What generous answers. So clear.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one in GNU awk. Only tested with your data and I don't know what happens if the data is not perfect, probably you get empty lines. Also, it uses `getline`, it might have issues, and I have no checks for its return values or checks for pretty much anything else either—but on the bright side, it's a good start for you to start practising your awk skills... :D

```
$ gawk '
BEGIN {
    o="A,B,B,C,C,C,C"                  # the predefined order
    n=split(o,p,/,/)                   # split to p array to be fetched
}
{
    c=d=$1                             # count of input lines
    while(c-->=0) {                    # keep reading til the reading is done
        getline
        a[$1][++i[$1]]=$0              # hash records to a 2-d array
    }
    print d
    print a["Linkages."][1]            # this may help in understanding the a array
    do {                               # once required amount is hashed
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++) {            # use the BEGIN defined index order
            print a[p[j]][++k[p[j]]]   # and output
        }
    } while((d-=n)>0)

    delete a;delete i;delete k         # regroup for next batch
}' file
```

Comment: thank you!  It is a good chance to practice my Awk.  I do need to.  I'll test it.  Might take me quite a while though!

Comment: Also, I just now looked at your expected output and noticed the number of lines and `Linkage` outputed also, which I have not included. I'll add them to the code in a sec.

Comment: that is very kind of you.  Exactly the kind of thing that would take me days to figure out in Awk!

Comment: @Ant to find out more about what James means when  he says using getline might have issues, read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline

Comment: @EdMorton, thank you for that.  I do need to make sure I understand all the pitfalls.  I have managed to get James's working.  There are a few minor formatting issues and sorting them out will be a good exercise for me.

Answer (score 2):

This solution works with the idea of breaking each 21-line chunk of input data into a 2-dimensional array with each sub-dimension consisting of 7 lines (`A,B,B,C,C,C,C`):

```
 blocks[1][  1] = A record
 blocks[1][2-3] = B records
 blocks[1][4-7] = C records

 blocks[2][  1] = A record
 blocks[2][2-3] = B records
 blocks[2][4-7] = C records

 blocks[3][  1] = A record
 blocks[3][2-3] = B records
 blocks[3][4-7] = C records
```

One `awk` solution using this 2-dimensional array idea; we'll populate the array as we process the `A` and `B` records, then backfill the array (ie, fill in the gaps) with the `C` records:

```
awk '

# function to print current array contents to stdout, then reset data structures for next block of lines

function print_blocks() {

    for (i=1; i<=a; i++)                  # loop through first  dimension indices
        for (j=1; j<=7; j++)              # loop through second dimension indices
            print blocks[i][j]

    delete blocks                         # clear array
    a=0                                   # reset first dimension index
    cblock=0                              # reset C block processing flag
}

NF == 1    {                              # single field on line, eg, "21" ?
             print_blocks()               # flush previously populated array
             print                        # print current line
             next                         # skip to next line
           }

/Linkages/ { print                        # print current line
             next                         # skip to next line 
           }

$1 == "A"  {                              # "A" record?
             blocks[++a][1]=$0            # store current line in array
                                          # and reset second dimension indexes ...
             b=2                          # for B records
             c=4                          # for C records
             next
           }

$1 == "B"  {                              # "B" record?
             blocks[a][b++]=$0            # store current line in array
             next
           }

$1 == "C"  {                              # "C" record?
             if (cblock==0)               # if first C record then:
                { a=0                     # reset first dimension index
                  cblock=1                # set flag to skip this logic for rest of C records
                }
             if (c==4) a++                # for each new set of 4x C records increment first dimension index

             blocks[a][c]=$0              # store current line in array
             c++                          # increment second dimension index but ...
             if (c>7) c=4                 # make sure second dimension index is always in the range 4-7
             next
           }

END { print_blocks() }                    # flush the last set of array data to stdout
' data.txt
```

**NOTES:**

- dependent on input data matching sample data (ie, `A,B,B,A,B,B,A,B,B,C,C,....`); if the input order is different then this code likely won't generate the desired output
- this is obviously hard coded for the samples given (ie, 21 lines of input data, 7 lines per output block of `A,B,B,C,C,C,C`)
- code could be modified to handle a more dynamic set of input data (but isn't that true of all code?)
- comments can be removed to de-clutter the code
- requires `GNU awk` for this particular implementation of a 2-dimensional array (aka array of arrays)

Against the given sample data (`data.txt`) the above generates:

```
     21
 Linkages. Iteration:1_1010
  A         1.010      -3.582      -3.135
  B         0.730      -4.428      -3.854
  B        -3.883       4.671       0.010
  C         3.944       2.513      -5.172
  C        -4.669       1.056       2.747
  C         0.645       0.001      -3.737
  C        -2.875      -1.233      -0.538
  A        -0.223       2.522      -4.893
  B         2.769       4.634       0.179
  B        -2.024      -3.640      -1.032
  C         4.279      -5.187      -2.820
  C         1.067      -2.279       2.021
  C         2.667      -1.558       0.588
  C         3.628      -0.025       2.464
  A         4.613       3.914       1.567
  B         2.746      -0.545       1.430
  B        -0.532       3.380      -2.107
  C        -0.023       1.717       1.175
  C         0.925      -1.548       2.273
  C         1.152       2.914       1.039
  C         0.878      -0.445      -0.948
     21
 Linkages. Iteration:1_1015
  A         1.010      -3.582      -3.135
  B         0.730      -4.428      -3.854
  B        -3.883       4.671       0.010
  C         3.944       2.513      -5.172
  C        -4.669       1.056       2.747
  C         0.645       0.001      -3.737
  C        -2.875      -1.233      -0.538
  A        -0.223       2.522      -4.893
  B         2.769       4.634       0.179
  B        -2.024      -3.640      -1.032
  C         4.279      -5.187      -2.820
  C         1.067      -2.279       2.021
  C         2.667      -1.558       0.588
  C         3.628      -0.025       2.464
  A         4.613       3.914       1.567
  B         2.746      -0.545       1.430
  B        -0.532       3.380      -2.107
  C        -0.023       1.717       1.175
  C         0.925      -1.548       2.273
  C         1.152       2.914       1.039
  C         0.878      -0.445      -0.948
```

Comment: thank you!  I look forward to trying this.  Really appreciate your effort to be so clear.  I am having to overcome a problem with a new laptop so it may take me quite a while to test this and James's solution above.  Please don't think I have forgotten about them; I am just slow and particularly with Awk!  Thank you again.

Comment: `a` - yes; `b` - no (and also not `c`); at this point the max second index (`7`) is hard-coded in several places (including assumption output is `A,B,B,C,C,C,C`) so will leave the `7` as is instead of complicating the code to 'keep track of' the max second index